# How to nested navigate between bottom tabs in React Navigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Given the structure:

- Bottom tabs with `lazy: false`

  - TabOne

    - MainScreen
  - TabTwo

    - MainScreen
    - LevelTwoScreen
    - LevelThreeScreen

How I can navigate from `TabOne -> MainScreen` to get the route: `TabTwo -> MainScreen -> LevelTwoScreen -> LevelThreeScreen`?

Below code dont work, just navigates to `TabTwoLevelTwoScreen`:

```js
navigation.navigate('TabTwoLevelTwoScreen', {
  screen: 'TabTwoLevelThreeScreen',
})
```

I tried this structure too, not sucess:

- Bottom tabs with `lazy: false`

  - TabOne

    - MainScreen
  - TabTwo

    - MainScreen
    - LevelTwoScreen
    - TabTwoNestedNavigator

      - LevelThreeScreen

This question started as a issue, see more [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10867).

Thanks!

Comment: If reset works why not use that?

Comment: @RajendranNadar makes sense, I'll go that way.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @RajendranNadar, I'll go with the `reset` option:

```js
navigation.reset({
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'TabTwo',
      state: {
        routes: [
          { name: 'MainScreen' },
          { name: 'LevelTwoScreen' },
          { name: 'LevelThreeScreen' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that once you navigate to the new page, pressing the back button completely closes the app.

Comment: Yes... A workaround for this is to preserve the previous state, but I haven't been able to implement it yet: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the nested navigator as you have, but you need to start from the top and work down. Reference https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

```
navigation.navigate('TabTwo', {
  screen: 'TabTwoNestedNavigator',
  params: {
      screen: 'LevelThreeScreen',
    },
})
```

This answer is still relevant. I think you are confused about how the nested navigator works. In your snack you are navigating to pages that don't exist. Updating your code to the following makes it work.

```
<Button
            title="Navigate to Tab Two - Level Three Screen"
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate('TabTwo', {
                screen: 'TabTwoNestedNavigator',
                params: {
                  screen: 'TabTwoLevelThreeScreen'
                },
              })
            }
          />
```

Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@halecolin1/nested-navigation-between-bottom-tabs-does-not-works-in-react-navigation-6

Comment: I tried, even specifying the whole route goes only one or two levels, see the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@gloredo/nested-navigation-between-bottom-tabs-does-not-works-in-react-navigation-6).

Comment: Yes, it works, but it's not the ideal solution, mainly because `goBack` goes wrong. For my use case I think `reset` is still the best, as back works as it should.

Comment: @GiovanedeLoredo With the reset method, pressing the back button completely closes the app